# OS X terminal "open" command and keeping focus on the command line

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I appreciate the "open" terminal command to launch OS X apps. When invoking the open command for any purpose, it is overwhelmingly likely that I will have at least one other command I would like to type into the terminal before tending to the application I have just summoned.

How do I keep focus on the terminal when using the *open* command?

Comment: Instead of piping through grep, have you just read the manage for open?

Comment: In deed I missed the -g option when I read through it the first time. I only started grepping when I ran out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I was looking for the opposite as the default behaviour seems to have changed in recent macOS versions and found out you have to uncheck Terminal → Secure Keyboard Entry to allow opened application to become frontmost.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `-g` flag.

From the `man` page:

> `-g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.`

Example: To open the folder at your current path, behind the current Terminal window:

```
open . -g
```

---

As a side note, it is often better to manually peruse the documentation for new commands, as the verbiage may be different from what you expect:

> i.e. "Do not bring the application to the foreground." vs. "Maintain terminal window focus."

Comment: Thanks, I did give the man page a good read through, though apparently I fell short of a good perusal. I did try a few others other than 'focus', like 'background', but 'foreground' never occurred to me.

Comment: No worries!  It happens to the best of us! :)